# How to print a specific integer value in a Bottle in YARP?

Tags: yarp

I'm trying to print a specific integer value of a Bottle by using cout (the Bottle contains only integer values), but it seems that this is a wrong way to do it. The command I used in a for loop is (the b Bottle is defined outside the loop):

```
std::cout << b.get(i) << std::endl;
```

The corresponding error is:

[image]

I'd like to see an example regarding the reading of a Bottle value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to get at the underlying type of the `Value`, if you know that it is indeed an `int32_t` (in other words `b.get(i).isInt32()` is `true`) then

```
std::cout << b.get(i).asInt32() << std::endl;
```

For the purposes of writing, without having to check the underlying type, you might also consider simply stringifying the `Value`

```
std::cout << b.get(i).toString() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Hello @CoryKramer thank you very much for your helpful answer. Can you tell me where to find the methods that I can use with get please (asInt, toString etc)? Why I can use two methods in sequence?

Comment: You can find them in the [`yarp::os::Value`](http://www.yarp.it/latest/classyarp_1_1os_1_1Value.html) documentation.

Comment: Please note that using `asInt()` is not racommended in new code, you should use `asInt32()` instead.

Comment: Hello @DanieleE.Domenichelli can you tell me the difference between asInt() and asInt32() please? Why asInt() is not reccomended?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Because `sizeof(int)` is platform-dependent, so to be sure the sender and receiver use an identical number of bytes you should use a fixed-width type like `int32` or `int64` as needed